# Verissimo Linter

Tags: system-verilog, linter

***** Warning: UNSPECIFIED_TOP: Please specify a -top module/entity/configuration in the project build file**

The above one is the warning I'm getting while running the Verissimo linter. Can anyone explain what would be the error.

I don't have a top file to Include.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the tools allow to compile more modules than required, so in the end it will have a bunch of "never instantiated" modules.

**Potentially every modules not instantiated can be a top level module.**

To avoid waste of elaboration time, it needs the top level module, so it can reconstruct the design hierarchy and focus on that.

Just add this argument `-top DUT`, with correct value, when executing tool.

Comment: It's not working, says unexpected argument -top

Comment: Please edit your question and share series of command you are issuing. If you have a multi-step flow, `-top` is needed in elaboration phase, not in compilation phase.

Comment: `-top` is a compilation directive. All compilation directives seems that have to be written in a file, `cmd <command file>`: `Mandatory. Compile using the specified compilation arguments file.`
https://dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/Run_in_Batch_Mode.html